# Intellij, says a file doesn't exist in web-inf, but it does

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I installed Intellij yesterday to see how it compared to Eclipse.

I've created a Maven project, imported the dependencies for Spring and setup everything I think I need to test the application runs.

The issue I have is that in the web.xml file it's marking one of the servlet configuration files as not found, when it does exist. I'm guessing this has something to do with the mapping of the web-inf folder, but I can't figure it out in Intellij

Here's the content of the web.xml file

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

I'm including a screenshot of my folder structure too.

[image]

The path was mapping fine, but then I change the artifact to be a war instead of exploded, and it seems to have broken something.

The error message on application run is;

```
IOException parsing XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring/dispatcher-servlet.xml]; nested exception is java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 12):

Probably this one will make it clearer:

1. project structure:

   [image: project structure]
2. set webapp folder as resources:

   [image: set webapp folder as resources]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12636017)

Comment: @zero298: I agree that this could use a bit more detail, but the image links are to the Stack Overflow imgur domain, and so are probably not susceptible to the usual kind of link rot.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this.

The web-inf folder was set as / in the paths section.

File > Project Structure 
Choose Modules
Select Web
Under Web Resources Directories, map the 'web' folder to '/'