# Why it throws JSP file does not exist exception

Tags: java, maven, jsp, intellij-idea

Why it still fails even after setting the `WebContent` as the `Resource`?

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33689318/intellij-says-a-file-doesnt-exist-in-web-inf-but-it-does) doesn't help

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) @ ESWebApp ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [ESWebApp] in 
[/Users/alim/practice/ElasticSearchAutoComplete/webApp-api/target/webapp-api]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp webResources 
[/Users/alim/practice/ElasticSearchAutoComplete/webApp-api/WebContent\WEB-INF\pages] to 
[/Users/alim/practice/ElasticSearchAutoComplete/webApp-api/target/webapp-api]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.863 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2018-11-25T21:17:49+08:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 25M/310M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-war-plugin:2.2:war (default-war) on project ESWebApp: Could not copy resource 
[/Users/alim/practice/ElasticSearchAutoComplete/webApp-api/WebContent\WEB-INF\pages]: File /Users/alim/practice/ElasticSearchAutoComplete/webApp-api/WebContent\WEB-INF\pages/autocomplete.jsp does not exist -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Please take a look.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why did you choose to break the Maven conventions? Just put the webapp resources where they should be: under src/main/webapp. https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Comment: Hi @JBNizet, It's a demo project from Github. You're right, it's supposed to be structured in Maven convention. Problem solved. Thanks